# how to set control's id dynamically in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

how can is set id dynamic with Eval method and setting the id from sql database to a controller , like this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="articlesqlfetch">
      <ItemTemplate>
           <strong > <%# Eval("title") %>  </strong> 
               <br>
<-! this is the line   ->
           <asp:HyperLink ID="_<%# Eval("id") %>" runat="server">قراءة المزيد</asp:HyperLink>         
      </ItemTemplate>
```

when do this it give me a Parser Error

Answer (score 3):

Using `Eval()` to provide dynamically generated ID is not allowed because you cannot bind to ID property of server controls, hence this code is wrong:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="_<%# Eval("id") %>" runat="server">some text</asp:HyperLink>
```

Instead, use `ItemDatabound` event for repeater control like this (assumed your ID is auto-generated identity field):

**Markup (ASPX)**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="articlesqlfetch" 
              OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%-- repeater contents --%>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="Hyperlink1" runat="server">some text</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink hyperlink = e.Item.FindControl("Hyperlink1") as HyperLink;
    if (hyperlink != null) 
    {
        hyperlink.ID = "_" + (e.Item.ItemIndex + 1).ToString(); // set ID from bound data
        hyperlink.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
        hyperlink.NavigateUrl = "some/uri/here"; // optional

        // other stuff
    }
}
```